# Is it possible to configure custom argument resolvers without @EnableWebMvc and WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**The context**

REST API implemented as Spring boot 1.5.3 project without `@EnableWebMvc`

**The objective**

For each API call create a UUID string and inject it into controller methods for audit purposes (the UUID is used in response body and for logging). Should be used as follows:

```
@PostMapping("/reserveCredits")
public ResponseEntity<Result> reserveCredits(String uuid) {
    ...
    ... new Result(uuid) ...
```

According to the documentation this can be achieved like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyWebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new MyCustomArgumentResolver());
    }
}
```

**The problem**

My whole project uses only REST controllers. I'm currently not using `@EnableWebMvc` and I don't want to introduce it now due to possible conflicts with my existing configuration. When I try using ...

```
@Autowired
private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter;
```

... in my `@Configuration` bean I get `BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping'` due to `ServletContext is required`.

**The questions**

1. How does Spring boot register its default argument resolvers without `@EnableWebMvc`?
2. Can I add custom argument resolver without `@EnableWebMvc`?
3. Is using `@EnableWebMvc` highly recommendable and I should retrofit it into my code?
4. Should I go for alternative solution?

**The alternatives**

- Invasive AOP that overrides method parameter value
- HandlerInterceptor that adds the uuid to request parameters and also updates response body

Comment: You don't need `@EnableWebMvc` as Spring Boot already does that for you . Just add an `@Configuration` class that extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer based on the comment by @M. Denium:

Yes it's possible without `@EnableWebMvc`. Configuration via extension of `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` does not have risk of regression impact. `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` doesn't have to be autowired into the config class.

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new MyCustomArgumentResolver());
    }
}
```